Is the Short-Time Fourier Transform an Isometry in $L_2(\mathbb{R}^d)$?
I have been studying the Fourier transform and came across an interesting property that it acts as an isometry in $L_2(\mathbb{R})$. Specifically, given a function $f \in L_1(\mathbb{R})$, the Fourier transform $\mathcal{F} f$ is defined as:
$$
(\mathcal{F}f)(y) := \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) e^{-ixy} \, dx , \quad y \in \mathbb{R}.
$$
For $f \in L_2(-\pi, \pi)$, it holds that:
$$
\|\mathcal{F} f\|_2^2 = \|f\|_2^2,
$$
indicating that the Fourier transform preserves the $L_2$ norm, thus acting as an isometry in $L_2(\mathbb{R})$.
Now, I am curious about the Short-Time Fourier Transform (STFT). The STFT of a signal $\psi \in L^2\left(\mathbb{R}^d\right)$ with respect to a window function $\varphi \in L^2\left(\mathbb{R}^d\right)$ is defined as:
$$
V_{\varphi} \psi(z)=\langle\psi, \pi(z) \varphi\rangle=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \psi(t) \overline{\varphi(t-x)} e^{-2 \pi i \omega \cdot t} \, dt, \quad z=(x, \omega)\in\mathbb R^{2d}.
$$
Given this definition, I would like to know if there is a similar result for the STFT in terms of preserving the $L_2$ norm. Specifically, is there an analogous property for the STFT that shows it acts as an isometry in $L_2(\mathbb{R}^d)$?
Any insights or references to relevant results would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I was confused by that $z=(x, \omega)$. I had to check another paper before it finally dawned to me that $z\in\mathbb R^{2d}$. You might want to edit your question to clarify this.

@GiuseppeNegro: Thank you for pointing that out. I have clarified this aspect in my question now.

You can generalise Parseval's theorem to STFT, but for an arbitrary window $\phi$, it is not an isometry from $L^2(\mathbb R^d)$ to $L^2(\mathbb R^{2d})$, you will need to normalise $\phi$ appropriately.
The usual proof assumes that $\phi\in L^\infty\cap L^2$. It then follows directly from Parseval's theorem:
$$
\begin{align}
V_\phi\psi(\tau,\nu) &= \int f(t)e^{-i2\pi\nu t}dt && f(t):= \psi(t)\phi(t-\tau)\\
\|V_\phi\psi\|_2^2 &= \int |V_\phi\psi|^2d\nu d\tau \\
&= \int \left|\int f(t)e^{-i2\pi\omega t}\right|^2d\nu d\tau \\
&= \int \int |f(t)|^2dt d\tau \\
&= \int \int |\psi(t)|^2|\phi(t-\tau)|^2dt d\tau \\
&= \|\psi\|_2^2\|\phi\|_2^2
\end{align}
$$
Assuming $\psi\in L^2$, $\phi\in L^\infty$ guarantees that $f\in L^2$ and Parseval's theorem applies. $\phi\in L^2$ is necessary for the final line. Thus, under these assumptions, it is an isometry if you normalise the window so that (which makes sense on dimensional grounds):
$$
\|\phi\|_2 = 1
$$
Btw, you can check this explicitly for easy functions like when $\psi$ and $\phi$ are gaussian (by varying the width of $\phi$, you can thus interpolate between the Fourier transform and the identity).
Note that the target space of $V_\phi$ is in some sense "twice" as large, so $V_\phi$ is redundant by its extra smoothness.

Thank you! I understand everything, but I can't explain this last part: $\iint|\psi(t)|^2|\phi(t-\tau)|^2 d t d \tau=|\psi|_2^2|\phi|_2^2$

@Mark: That is Fubini

Yes exactly. Another way of seeing it is to change variables $\tau'=t-\tau$
